# How to calculate distance between 2 points (Lambert EU projection coordinates)

Tags: coordinates, distance, coordinate-systems

I'm a real noob when it comes to coordinate systems/projections and calculations, so please speak to me as a dummy :)

I have coordinate data (it's written that this is Lambert EU projection), which looks as follows:

```
R A00   x_center    y_center
1 svk   519922,4822 2089546,836
2 aut   486321,4714 2087458,014
3 aut   493858,9945 2085882,625
```

Now my first trouble is, I can find a whole bunch of calculations and formulas dealing with WGS84 coordinates, but I've never seen such coordinates as above.

The target is:

- I would need to calculate the distance in km between two points, for example row 1 (x, y) and row 2 (x, y).
- I would need the easiest formula available (high precision is not required)
- The calculation should then be done in Oracle PL/SQL (PL/SQL code as your answer is nice to have but not required, I'm more concerned with the given coordinates and how to calculate distance in kilometers with them).

Can someone point me to the right direction? Thanks

Comment: Hello, would you mind to answer?

Comment: Hi, I will check on Monday and hopefully accept/close the case, thanks for your answer so far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I remember the Lambert coordinates are already in cartesian meters.

so simply use `sqrt(dx*dx +dy*dy)` to get the distance in meters where `dx=x2-x1` and `dy=y2-y1`.

If you have to transform them to WGS84, then it gets more complex:

First you must find out the exact name of the projection, best by their EPSG projection number. (their is more than one Lambert projection, e.g the french Lambert 2 etendue)

Then you have to search harder, there are documents, describing the Lambert Projection.

Comment: Hi, I got also an answer from the company giving us the data. They said that the distance is calculated as sqrt((x1-x2)² + (y1-y2)²) - so your answer was nearly there ;-)

Comment: No, not nearly there, my answer is exactly the same; dx is the same as x2-x1, in technics it is also called deltaX, i thought that is well known. (You learn that in school (Pythagoras, euklidean or cartesian distance), Feel free to upvote and accept.

Comment: @ToniKanoni my answer is perfectly correct and identical to that of your data provider (since dx = x2 - x1) and dx² = dx * dx; (dx * dx os more efficient, than to call Math.pow())

Comment: Argh, yes i see, youve been right all along. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Any idea how much of an approximation this is to the true spherical distance?

Comment: There is no true distance. spherical is not perfect, because the earth is an more an ellipsoid than a sphere. There are formulas for ellipsoidal distance (e,g Look for Vicencis formula / algorithm). Further Deviation alsways depends on the Location and the distance. You can try it out: convert the lambert to wgs84, calculate  distance with a) haversine fomrula, b) with vicency and compare them.